# .Copy(Rectangle r) method for UMat in EmguCV(3.1)

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, copy, emgucv

I'm programming in C# using EmguCV(3.1) library. In previous version of this library there is an `Image` (for example Image) instance having `.Copy(Rectangle r)` method.

How can I crop an `UMat` instance using a `Rectangle` instance?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "ROI" property (region of intrest):

```
image.ROI = new Rectangle(5,5,20,20);
//Now every operation on image will be on the bounded area
var cpy = image.copy();
//cpy size is 20x20
```